# My CNN model always predict one class when i test my model

Tags: python, keras, tensor, conv-neural-network

I am new to Machine Learning. I have tried to make a model i learned from internet and got 81% accuracy on two species but when i test the model my model always predict one specie. Help me pls i'm confused Thanks you

Epoch 50/50
46/46 [==============================] - 104s 2s/step - loss: 0.3790 - accuracy: 0.8185 - val_loss: 0.2218 - val_accuracy: 0.8050

```
import numpy as np
from keras.preprocessing import image

img_pred = image.load_img(r'D:\Know Wood Laptop\Anatomy-master\Test\ws3\1315_3.jpg' , target_size = (150 , 150))
#img_pred = image.load_img(r'D:\Know Wood Laptop\Anatomy-master\Test\ws1\806_1.jpg' , target_size = (150 , 150))

img_pred = image.img_to_array(img_pred)
image = img_pred/255.0
img_pred = np.expand_dims(img_pred,axis=0)

rslt = model.predict(img_pred)


print(rslt)
if rslt[0][0]==0:
    prediction = "ws1"
else:
    prediction = "ws3"

print (prediction)
```

[[0.]]
ws1

Comment: Judging from the `val_accuracy` it's well-trained. As I can see, you have tried just two images at which the model could be wrong. Try some more

Comment: Sir Yes it is giving one some of the second specie but when i put test image of first specie i always get correct result. Why is this?

Comment: Is your data balanced? Maybe the count of `ws1` in the data is bigger than the other classes and your model learned that most of the time it will be `ws1`

Comment: @Anwarvic Sir, i tried to have same amount of images for both species and then applied augmentation.

Comment: @Anwarvic Sir i have another question is my model is very well trained on first specie and not good on second specie or is there any other reason?

Comment: Try to generate the confusion matrix of the validation set and post the output

Comment: Sir i am new to Machine Learning i don't know about it do you have code sample of it?

Comment: The confusion matrix is the technical term for getting some intuition behind the model results. Check out [this link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/confusion-matrix-machine-learning/)